Get correct vector embeddings from RedisVL while querying results
I am using RedisVL in my project, to store some data. The schema.yaml file for creating the index in the RedisVL looks like this:
version: '0.1.0'
index:
  name: event-index
  prefix: event

fields:
  - name: lp
    type: tag
  - name: customer_token
    type: tag
  - name: event_type
    type: tag
  - name: corrected_lp
    type: tag
  - name: embedding
    type: vector
    attrs:
      algorithm: flat
      dims: 59
      distance_metric: L2
      datatype: float32

Now when I load some data into this index like this:
# event is a pydantic model having fields lp, customer_token, event_type, corrected_lp
# embed the image using an embedding model
vec = to_embedding(image)

index = await search_index()
info = {
        'lp': event.lp,
        'embedding': vec.tobytes(),
        'customer_token': event.customer_token,
        'event_type': event.event_type
    }
if event.corrected_lp:
    info['corrected_lp'] = event.corrected_lp
await index.load([info],
      keys=[f'event:{identifier}'],
      ttl=config['index']['ttl'].get(int))

It loads the data into the index correctly.
When I want to get the same data from index after using a FilterQuery it return all the values as a list of dictionary.
index = await search_index()
        
filter_exp = ((Tag("customer_token") == filters.customer_token) &
              (Tag("event_type") == filters.event_type)) 
        
filter_query = FilterQuery(
            return_fields=["event_type", "lp", "corrected_lp",
                           "customer_token", "embedding"],
            filter_expression=filter_exp)
        
res = await index.query(filter_query)

if not res:
    return None
# Converting the list of dictionaries to a list of Event objects
events = [
         Event(event_type=event['event_type'],
               lp=event['lp'],
               corrected_lp=event.get('corrected_lp'),
               customer_token=event['customer_token'],
               vector=list(np.frombuffer(event['embedding'],dtype=np.float32)),
               ) for event in res
         ]

The result (res) obtained from the index after the FilterQuery shows the embedding values to be a normal string rather than a bytestring which was expected as it was converted while loading into index. How can I get the original encoded bytestring from the string.
If I use anything like string.encode() then it cannot interpret the correct format.
Any help on this will be very helpful.

The issue has been reported by:

https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/2772
https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/2275
https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/2164

Watch the issues to track the progress.
